# Export SQL Server database to XML Optimization

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have SQL Server database for articles.

`Articale` table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[T_Articale]
(
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Title] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [Text] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [LocationID] [int] NULL,
    [TribeID] [int] NULL,
    [ArticaleText] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [ArticaleDate] [date] NULL,
    [SearchID] [int] NULL,
    [ClassificationID] [int] NULL,
    [CountryID] [int] NULL,
    [isLocal] [int] NULL,
    [Note] [nvarchar](150) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_T_Articale] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
)
```

Where `ArticaleText` is the content of the article with formatting (HTML tags)

`Files` table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[T_Articale_Files]
(
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Artricle_id] [int] NULL,
    [FileName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [FileData] [varbinary](max) NULL,
    [FileData2] [nvarchar](max) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_T_Articale_Files] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
)
```

Here the user can attach files with the article `FileData` binary column is the actual file

I have a function to export the database to XML

```
var xmlFileData = "";
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
var tables = new[] { //List of DB Tables  };

foreach (var table in tables)
{
    var query = "SELECT * FROM " + table;

    SqlConnection conn = GetConnection();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);

    conn.Open();

    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable(table);
    da.Fill(dt);

    conn.Close();
    conn.Dispose();

    ds.Tables.Add(dt);
}

//  xmlFileData = ds.GetXml();
var xmlstream = new StringWriter();
ds.WriteXml(xmlstream, XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);
string xmlWithSchema = xmlstream.ToString();
File.WriteAllText("D://SelectiveDatabaseBackup.xml", xmlWithSchema);
```

My problem is now the database grows to 700MB (if I take a script with data)
my XML function give out of memory exception

What fixes or optimizations can solve that problem (clustering, indexing ...)
(the database will continue to grow)

Edit

Why I need XML??

The situation is I have some computers that can not access the server and does not have SQL Server installed so I need to make that data available without DB Engine. So the first thought was XML. It is not for backup purpose.

It is a Windows Forms application.

Comment: You should use the built-in backup mechanism rather than a homebrew approach, not least because it supports differentials which will save space.

Comment: wHAT DO YOU MEAN BY built-in backup mechanism??  will that built-in backup mechanism give me XML File for the whole DB

Comment: I mean SQL Server has an efficient, reliable & flexible built in system to backup databases, you should use it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/backup-overview-sql-server - It does not use XML, XML is not space efficient and is a terrible choice for serializing binary data like varbinary.

Comment: Fastest method would be to use one of the built in command line tools that comes with SQL Server.  You can put results output results into csv file.  I usually run from c# using Process class.  I also put into a background process so it doesn't hang up a Window Form application.  Some of my queries take over 1/2 hour to run using SQLCMD.exe.  In c# it was taking hours to run equivalent.

Comment: i have Edited the post for more explaination

Comment: Why are you exporting the data as XML? What do you expect to achieve from this, except a bloated text file that's very expensive to read?

Comment: As for "can not access the server and does not have SQL Server installed" Why not install it then? Why not install SQL Server Express? Or even SQLite if the data volume is small enough? Replication is *already* availalbe in SQL Server. If you need to replicate 700MB of data, then you definitely *need* a server on those machines. If the actual data that needs to be replicated is less, you can get away with copying changed data from the server to a local SQLite file periodically

Comment: this is my situation and these computers are not allwed to install any thing and it is not my decision to make i have to handle the situation as it is

Comment: The out of memory exception is being caused by windows forms not SQLServer. Create the entire solution in a stored procedure then call the procedure from the windows forms application.

Answer (score 0):

Let’s consider an example for generating a XML:

```
CREATE PROC GenerateXMLproc

AS

SELECT [Name], ProductNumber, Color

FROM dbo.Product

FOR XML raw(‘Product’), elements, root(‘Products’)
```

Now we’ll discuss the above mentioned options for saving this XML data:

1. **Using CLR Stored Procedure:** In this method we can create a CLR stored procedure which will take the XML data generated, file name & location of the file as input parameters. And then it can process that XML as per the requirements and can save that XML file to the desired location.

**Creating CLR stored procedure:**

```
[Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlProcedure]

public static void SaveXMLOutput(SqlXml XmlData, SqlString Filename)

{

             //Save the XML data being passed to the SP to a file location

      //specify the name of the file suppiled to the SP

      XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

      SqlPipe output = SqlContext.Pipe;

      xmlDoc.LoadXml(XmlData.Value);

      xmlDoc.Save(Filename.Value);

}
```

> //This will give a DLL ‘SaveXMLOutput.dll’
>   **Creating Assembly in SQL Server**

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY SaveXMLOutputAssembly

from ‘C:\Temp\SaveXMLOutput.dll’

WITH PERMISSION_SET = EXTERNAL_ACCESS
```

> –‘ trustworthy ’ property of the database must be set to ‘ON’ before
>   using the EXTERNAL_ACCESS for the aseembly.
>
> –This can be done using ALTER DATABASE [DataBaseName] SET trustworthy
>   ON

**Creating stored procedure from the Imported DLL/Assembly:**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SaveXMLOutput

@xmldata XML,

@filename nvarchar(1024)

AS

EXTERNAL NAME SaveXMLOutputAssembly.[XMLOutput].SaveXMLOutput
```

> –XMLOutput is the name of class and SaveXMLOutput is the name of the
>   SP as defined in the class
>
> –Executing this SP

```
execute SaveXMLOutput ‘Pass the XML Data generated from other SP’

,‘ C:\Temp\MyXML.xml’
```